# Can I use a private method inside my prototype function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm learning OO JavaScript, so this question may sound odd. **Problem**: `normalize` function should be private, that is not accessible/writable outside. **Question**: how can I access `normalize` from inside `prepare` prototype function?

```js
var AuthHmac = AuthHmac || (function(_, CryptoJS) {
    function AuthHmac(options) {
        var options = options || {},
            normalize = function(s) { return s.toLowerCase(); };

        this.additionalHeaders = options.additionalHeaders || {};
    };

    AuthHmac.prototype.prepare = function(request) {
        request.headers = request.headers || {};

        _.each(this.additionalHeaders, function(value, name) {
            request.headers[this.normalize(name)] = value;
        });
    };

    return AuthHmac;

})(_, CryptoJS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. JavaScript does not have any concept of private or public properties and hence people use closures and scoping as "hack" to simulate privacy. But this comes at a cost, namely that the prototype methods don't have access to these "private" properties.

In your specific example though, `normalize` could as well be defined outside the constructor function, since it does not depend on anything inside the constructor function:

```
var AuthHmac = AuthHmac || (function(_, CryptoJS) {

    var normalize = function(s) { return s.toLowerCase(); };

    function AuthHmac(options) {
        var options = options || {};
        this.additionalHeaders = options.additionalHeaders || {};
    };

    AuthHmac.prototype.prepare = function(request) {
        request.headers = request.headers || {};

        _.each(this.additionalHeaders, function(value, name) {
            request.headers[normalize(name)] = value;
        });
    };

    return AuthHmac;

})(_, CryptoJS);
```

Comment: I disagree to call lexical scoping and closures a "hack". The cost is trivial too.

Comment: That is, `var normalize` is a local variable and I can use it from within `AuthHmac`, right? Any disadvance defining `normalize` outside the constructor (as you proposed)?

Comment: @jAndy: If those concepts are used to simulate private properties, than it is a "hack" IMO (and note that I put hack in quotes. It's a create application of the concepts).

Comment: @Gremo: Since `normalize` does not depend on anything inside the constructor, you might as well just define it outside.

Comment: @FelixKling: there is no simulation. it is working as intended.

Comment: @jAndy: Simulation does not mean it does not work as intended ;) I think we have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @FelixKling: I might be picky on that one, but it sounds like.. "using some not meant to be technology" to achieve a certain result. But taking advantage of lexical scoping to achieve privacy is not that IMO.

Comment: @jAndy: Using it for privacy, encapsulation, etc., is all fine. But I'm talking specifically about "private properties" and the way it is used to implement private "properties" generally does not allow you to make full use of prototype methods. In this case, lexical scoping is used to simulate something (private properties) which the language does not provide.

Answer (score 1):

No, not if that `normalize` function is scoped to the constructor function.

However, since your function does not need to be privileged (i.e. have access to the constructor's local variables), you can easily put it outside and it still will be private to your module:

```
var AuthHmac = AuthHmac || (function(_, CryptoJS) {

    function normalize(s) { return s.toLowerCase(); }

    function AuthHmac(options) {
        var options = options || {};

        this.additionalHeaders = options.additionalHeaders || {};
    };

    AuthHmac.prototype.prepare = function(request) {
        request.headers = request.headers || {};

        _.each(this.additionalHeaders, function(value, name) {
            request.headers[normalize(name)] = value;
//                          ^^^^^^^^^
//    No `this.`! "private attributes" in JS are variables, not properties
        });
    };

    return AuthHmac;

})(_, CryptoJS);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var AuthHmac = AuthHmac || (function(_, CryptoJS) {

function normalize(s) { return s.toLowerCase(); }

function AuthHmac(options) {
    var options = options || {};

    this.additionalHeaders = options.additionalHeaders || {};
};

AuthHmac.prototype.prepare = function(request) {
    request.headers = request.headers || {};

    _.each(this.additionalHeaders, function(value, name) {
        request.headers[normalize(name)] = value;
    });
};

return AuthHmac;

})(_, CryptoJS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the `normalise` function as a named function inside the scope, instead of putting it in a property of your object:

```
var AuthHmac = AuthHmac || (function(_, CryptoJS) {

  function normalize(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase();
  }

  function AuthHmac(options) {
    var options = options || {};

    this.additionalHeaders = options.additionalHeaders || {};
  };

  AuthHmac.prototype.prepare = function(request) {
    request.headers = request.headers || {};

    _.each(this.additionalHeaders, function(value, name) {
        request.headers[normalize(name)] = value;
    });
  };

  return AuthHmac;

})(_, CryptoJS);
```